# Where do I start with POST signin-oidc errors?

Tags: .net-core, openid-connect, asp.net-core-middleware

I am seeing this error in the logs quite frequently when the `POST /signin-oidc` endpoint is hit and I don't know where to start investigating it.

The stack trace only reports code within the donet core library code, not something in the app code:

```
System.Exception:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=3.1.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=3.1.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware+<Invoke>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration, Version=3.1.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol+<ProcessRequests>d__214`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=3.1.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Inner exception System.Exception handled at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1+<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext:
```

The code in question is a dotnet core 3.1 web app hosted on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

One place to start looking is to look in the logs provided by the authentication middleware in ASP.NET Core. You might need to lower the debug level, perhaps by setting it in appsettings.json, like

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

One potential reason for errors is if you have multiple instances of you ASP.NET Core client running.